# How to create service/port specific subdomains in OpenBSD vm

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, subdomain, openbsd, openbsd-httpd

I am creating a website in an OpenBSD vm, and I plan to have different services on it that will be pointed to by their respective subdomains (irc.example.com -> example.com:6697, img.example.com -> example.com:80, etc).

I also plan on img.example.com hosting the images over http for example.com/www.example.com, both of which on port 80/443. Because vmm cannot do nested vm's, my initial plans of containing each subdomain in its own virtual environment and pointing to each with a relayd reverse proxy will not work. I was wondering how I could achieve this functionality without vm's.

Here is a diagram drawing out my intentions:[image: simple diagram of subdomains inside of example.com vm]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information it seems the answer is just generally:

The Packet Filter (`pf`) is what you use to route the packets to each service and based on what you have posted so far, it appears you can use just `pf` and the web server (`httpd`), unless there is some other reason you feel you need a reverse proxy.

Simple `pf.conf` example:

```
ext_if = "vio0"
ext_srvcs_in = "{ 70, 80, 443, 6697 }"
set skip on lo
# Not mentioned in question, but assuming you want SSH with common adaptive config:
pass in quick on $ext_if proto tcp to port ssh \
    keep state (max-src-conn 15, max-src-conn-rate 5/3, \
    overload <bruteforce> flush global)
pass out quick on $ext_if
block all
pass in on $ext_if proto {tcp, udp} to port $ext_srvcs_in
```

When you configure your services, they should bind to the ports and `pf` will route to them. For multiple subdomains on `httpd` just use multiple server blocks as described in `httpd.conf(5)`. For example:

```
types { include "/usr/share/misc/mime.types" }

server "example.com" {
        alias "www.example.com"
        listen on * port 80
        listen on * tls port 443
        tls {
                certificate "/etc/ssl/example.com.fullchain.pem"
                key "/etc/ssl/private/example.com.key"
        }
        location "/.well-known/acme-challenge/*" {
                root "/htdocs/example.com"
                request strip 2
        }
        root "/var/www/htdocs/example.com"
        directory index index.htm
}

server "img.example.com" {
        listen on * port 80
        listen on * tls port 443
        tls {
                certificate "/etc/ssl/example.com.fullchain.pem"
                key "/etc/ssl/private/example.com.key"
        }

        location "/.well-known/acme-challenge/*" {
                root "/htdocs/img.example.com
                request strip 2
        }
        root "/var/www/htdocs/img.example.com"
        directory index index.htm
}
```